# Is the proxy issue handled gracefully in Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring

I can't find any documentation answering this question.

To summarize:

- I have a bean that implements an interface.
- I set proxy-target-class to false.
- I toggle between Spring 3.2.17 and 4.3.3 versions.
- When I use Spring 3.2.17, the main class throws this:

  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7 cannot be cast to
         com.package1.Camera
              at com.package1.App.main(App.java:8)

  This is what I expected. This is the correct behaviour because the JDK  proxy class was generated.
- But when I use Spring 4.3.3, no exception is thrown and main class runs properly.

  The CGLIB proxy class was generated. But why was it generated when I set the proxy-target-class to false?

Here are the source files:

**App.java**

```
package com.package1;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        Camera camera = (Camera) context.getBean("camera");
        camera.snap();
        context.close();
    }
}
```

**ICamera.java**

```
package com.package1;
public interface ICamera {}
```

**Camera.java**

```
package com.package1;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("camera")
public class Camera implements ICamera {
    public void snap() {
        System.out.println("SNAP!");
    }
}
```

**Logger.java**

```
package com.package1;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class Logger {

    @Pointcut("execution(void com.package1.Camera.snap())")
    public void cameraSnap() {

    }

    @Before("cameraSnap()")
    public void beforeAdvice() {
        System.out.println("Before advice...");
    }

}
```

**beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd">


    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.package1">
    </context:component-scan>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="false"></aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.package1</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test-app</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Is it even a proxy... I don't see any aspects... No aspects that match, no proxy, no error...

Comment: I don't know why but this code still working .

Comment: You can check my code here : https://github.com/tuyendev/SpringCore/tree/master/Example/SpringCore

Comment: @M.Deinum, I just added the aspect class: Logger.java

Comment: The code in your repo doesn't have an aspect... No proxy will be created as there is nothing to create a proxy for.

Comment: @M.Deinum I believe you are referring to tuyendev's repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thru trial and error I had come up with the answer.

**App.java**

```
package com.package1;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        Object o = context.getBean("camera");
        System.out.println("class=" + o.getClass());
        Camera camera = (Camera) context.getBean("camera");
        camera.snap();
        context.close();
    }
}
```

proxy-target-class still defaults to false.

But now, Spring 4 is smart enough what proxy will it generate (JDK or CGLIB).

- If you have an empty interface, it will generate a CGLIB proxy.

**ICamera.java**

```
package com.package1;
public interface ICamera {}
```

- Otherwise, JDK proxy will be generated.

**ICamera.java**

```
package com.package1;

public interface ICamera {
    void snap();
}
```

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

When you set proxy-target-class = false, CGLIB Proxy still creates with same formula JDK Proxy.
In Spring docs, they said:

> Spring AOP uses either JDK dynamic proxies or CGLIB to create the proxy for a given target object. (JDK dynamic proxies are preferred whenever you have a choice).
>
> If the target object to be proxied implements at least one interface then a JDK dynamic proxy will be used. All of the interfaces implemented by the target type will be proxied. If the target object does not implement any interfaces then a CGLIB proxy will be created.

See more : [Proxying mechanisms](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html)

Comment: Understand that proxy will be created. The question is still why does Spring 4 doesn't throw the proxy issue?